# How does a function containing console.log() in it behave, when its return value is passed to a console.log as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, console.log

I have created a function that displays a parameter value via console.log() within it, and returns a value as well.  So I played a bit, and called another console.log, where I've put two parameters, first being a string, and a second parameter being this function that I've created that has a console.log() in it.  The output confuses me.

```js
let fun = function (m = 5) {
  console.log(m);
  return 'hi';
};

console.log('hello', fun());
```

I expected the output to be 'hello' followed by 5 and then 'hi', but the actual output is 5 followed by 'hello' and 'hi'.  Please help, as this doesn't make sense as it is. Thanks.

Comment: All parameters are evaluated before the call

Answer (score 2):

`fun()` has to be *fully* evaluated **before** its return value can be passed back to the calling function.

Since `fun()` includes `console.log(m)`, `m` is logged first.

Answer (score 1):

When `console.log('hello', fun());` is executed, both arguments need to be evaluated before `console.log` can be called.

The evaluation of `fun()` executes the code inside the function. `console.log(m)` is called here, so this output is first. The return value (`'hi'`) is then used as the second argument to `console.log`. Only after this is the second log actually printed.

Comment: It's interesting how javascript looks for other console.logs within parameter functions, and displays them first, then aligns other expressions with return values of parameter functions from first to next.  I am wondering about the logic behind it, like what purpose would it serve?